# Handle authentication in a Service Worker for a React App

Tags: authentication, reactjs, redux, react-router, service-worker

I have a React app rendering client-side, in which I handle authentication the following way:

1. Upon loading, the app fires an AJAX request to the backend, basically asking whether the user's session is valid ;
2. It updates the app's state with the server's response ;
3. It renders the "/" route accordingly (the homepage if the session is invalid, a dashboard if it is valid).

(Maybe there are better solutions for handling this in front-end applications, I'm all ears if you have ideas)

This works pretty well, but introducing Service Workers into the mix and trying to turn the app into an offline-first progressive web app seems... complicated.

On the one hand, if I don't cache the "Am I logged in ?" request and the app is offline, the app will always render the homepage.
On the other hand, if I do cache the AJAX request, the users will eventually be shown an empty dashboard because their sessions will have expired and the server will be throwing 403s.

Is there a way to handle this effectively?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my problem by taking a different approach: I now persist the state in localStorage.

This way, when the user arrives on the app, he is presented with stale data from his last visit. Meanwhile, a "Am I logged in?" request is fired in the background.

- If it is succesful and returns `true`, the other AJAX requests get fired and fill the app with fresh data ;
- If it is successful and returns `false`, the state is updated accordingly and the user redirected to the homepage ;
- If the request is unsuccessful (i.e. the app is offline) the app keeps showing stale data from last session in the dashboard. We don't know if the user's session is still valid, but we can't retreive any data so it does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is adding a /verifyToken (assuming you are using some kind of token to validate the session) in your back-end api to check if the token is valid.

So you cache your session token. If the app is offline it shows the dashboard.

If the app is online, you fire a request to /verifyToken to check is the session is still valid. If it is then you continue to dashboard. If it isn't you redirect them back to homepage (or the sign in page).

Edit:
When your app is online, you can technically fire a request to any authorized route and check if the response was 403 (in case you can't modify the backend). If it is then you can send them back to sign in page.

Comment: Right, this "fallback when receiving 403s" solution seems like a decent fix.
But I hoped there would be a more Service Worker-specific solution, like a way to renew the session without an interaction from the user...
Showing the homepage or the login form in what's supposed to be an app seems wrong to me.

Comment: Well, what you can also do is refresh your token? so you check the token, if it's not a valid token you ignore it. But if it is a expired token you can generate a new token and use that.

Again that depends on if you have access to backend api to make changes or if your backend api supports it.